# After I implemented a linked list in python, how do I free the memory of it?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Here is my implementation of the node of linked list

```
class ListNode(object):
def __init__(self,val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None
```

Base on my understanding of how python manages the memory, I think when I need to free the memory, I still need to use a function like this below, isn't it?

```
def free_linked_list(head):
    while head:
        next_node = head.next
        del head  # As long as no variable is pointed to this node, it would be freed from the memory. Is it?
        head = next_node
```

So, my problem is:
1. Is my understanding right?
2. If not, how could I free the memory of this linked list? Or python has already do it for me?

Comment: If you delete (or lose your reference to) the head node, then python should free the rest of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your understanding is correct. As long as the object is no longer referenced, Python's garbage collection will take care of it. You can also explicitly call `gc.collect()` to force garbage collection if you really need too. Here's a link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that Python uses garbage collection in lieu of manual memory management like you might have in C or other low level languages. This means that the Python runtime utilizes a background thread that periodically marks and removes "orphaned" objects that are not referenced by any other object in your program.

In fact, your example is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. As long as there's no reference to the head of the list, then the entire list is "stranded" and will by garbage collected by the Python runtime.

Comment: But this linked list node, is relatively different in my perspective. Even though I have deleted the refence to the head node, but this head node still have a refefence to its next node. And how about the head node's value, and its pointer to next node? Thus, How does python know that the head node should be disposed?

Comment: What do you mean? Different in what respect?

Comment: Oh! I now understand! The nodes in the list would all lost its reference if the reference to the head is removed.

Comment: But, I got another question. In python, how could I know which variables still exists in the memory?